# Core graphics stroke around existing, irregular image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, core-graphics, stroke

Is it possible to take a pre-existing UIImage of an irregular shape, like the silhouette of an island or a user-drawn blob, and then use Core Graphics to draw an outline of a given width and color along its edges? I'm assuming an otherwise transparent UIImage, with a single solid shape. Interior or exterior strokes are acceptable, although exterior is preferred.

It seems like that ought to be possible, but I'm a CG newbie and all of my research is just turning up tutorials and answers about adding stroke to an image as it is being drawn, or else along a simple, pre-defined path that can be hard-coded.  I'm finding surprisingly little information about dealing with irregular images based on the method's input.

I know the SO community prefers code samples and such, but I honestly don't know where to start.  My only conceptual lead is, if it's possible to get a path based on the outline of an existing shape, I could stroke that path?  But I don't know how to get a path based on an irregular, unpredictable input image.

Can anyone help a newbie out?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to apply a [Sobel edge detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) to the alpha channel of the image. Once you have the edges defined you could convert them to vectors and then stroke them. Or you could leave them as pixels and apply something like a [dilation filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) to them.